# SQL, optimizing my query: UNION vs OR

Tags: sql, performance, select

I have a query along these lines:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.surname
FROM employees e, cities c
WHERE e.cityid = c.id
UNION
SELECT e.firstname, e.surname
FROM employees e, cities c
WHERE e.cityid = ''
UNION
SELECT e.firstname, e.surname
FROM employees e, cities c
WHERE e.cityid is null
```

It works perfectly fine, but I don't like that I have to repeat myself several times (3 times, separated by 2 unions).

I have therefore tried to write the query like this:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.surname
FROM employees e, cities c
WHERE (e.cityid = c.id OR e.cityid = '' OR e.cityid is null)
```

It also works perfectly fine, but it's extremely slow compared to the first query with the unions.

So is it possible to write the query in another way, so I get the performance of the first query without repeating myself several times.

Thanks.

Comment: did you index the columns? and what db backend do you use?

Comment: ` e.cityid = '' ` :  e.cityid is a varchar or char key ?

Comment: Why do 2 out of 3 branches not have any join condition between the tables? What is this query actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: You are probably after [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

Answer (score 2):

This has the same semantics as your original query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.firstname,
                e.surname
FROM   employees e
       LEFT JOIN cities c
         ON e.cityid = c.id
WHERE  e.cityid = ''
        OR e.cityid IS NULL
        OR c.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.surname
FROM employees e left join cities c
on e.cityid = c.id OR e.cityid = '' OR e.cityid is null
```

Comment: Won't this return all employees with no filtering?

Comment: on e.cityid = c.id OR e.cityid = '' OR e.cityid is null.. This is the filter condition

Comment: But by putting the `e.cityid = '' OR e.cityid is null` into the `on` clause the `left join` will preserve rows from `e` that neither meet that condition or have a matching row in `c`